# Miniature electric or manual jacks?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power-electronics, hydraulics

This is the top part of a basic sit/stand base I'm making.  It is a monitor platform and sliding keyboard tray.

[image]

Instead of the large base with 2 rods on each end [(like this design see video at bottom of page)](http://www.codeovereasy.com/2013/09/diy-adjustable-desk-for-under-25/) I'm looking for another way to raise and lower the desk.

The one issue with the base design, is that in the lowered position, the platform is already 4 inches up off the desk and will then have to sit on top of the base another 3.5 inches or so. The addition of a base anymore than an inch or so would be too high...(unless the platform does *not* have to sit on the base)

I'm looking for some sort of electronic or manual jack that could fit under the over-hanging portion of the platform. Perhaps a small one on each of the 4 corners.... or maybe 1 longer one for each side? (The platform is 33"X18")

I would like to raise the desk about 12 inches from where the top sits now. Also will be in an office setting so can't be too loud.

Are there any type of devices that could be engineered... or purchased... or somewhere in between, that can work for this application or have been use for something similar in the past?

Some other random ideas I have had: some sort of accordion or scissor lift that attaches across to the bottom of each vertical leg of the platform....or maybe air bags?

Here is a close up of the leg and edge hanging over.
[image]

**Update1**

or for a more manual design, I came up with scissor sliding rods with rails. On one side, it would have a sliding rail attached to the top of the over hang, and then a rail attached to some sort of base - that would fit beneath the over hang:

[image]

Has something like this ever been proven to work decent?

The only problem with the [scissors as a whole unit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDU43UTL2Yg) is that the top would need to be attached to the legs of the platform...and not sure how many inches it would add..in addition, the whole desk would move forward and back, along with up and down (and I have no idea what the kid is saying...probably some thing like I'm 8 and smarter than you).

Comment: Do you want to cut a hole in the table to house some of the mechanism?

Comment: @ratchet-freak: sure, as long as it works well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the fixed point of the rail on the back on both the upper *and* lower rails in the video you linked they are on opposite sides leading to a side to lateral movement.

Comment: Good point. but in that case, not sure how far forward will the movement of the platform will be... .this looks like the right way to do it and it did not have much forward/back movement: http://www.instructables.com/id/Liftable-Stand-up-Rising-Desk-Table/

Comment: Depends on how steep you don't want the legs too steep or it will wobble because the support is too narrow. If you have an angle set it's a bit of trig to work out the height gain per set of links. Also in that album the fixed points are in front on both sides.